# Installing courier-mta causes sendmail to be installed instead

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt, sendmail, courier

My Debian workstation will not install courier-mta.  The command `aptitude install courier-mta` appears to complete without error, but actually installs sendmail instead.

## What I did

I'll start without any packages installed which provide mail-transfer-agent:

```
dpkg --get-selections 'courier*' 'sendmail*' 'exim*' sensible-mda | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends
...
root@treebeard:/etc/logcheck/violations.ignore.d$ dpkg -l 'courier*' 'sendmail*' 'exim*' sensible-mda
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-===================================================================================================
un  exim4                                           <none>                                                    (no description available)
dpkg-query: no packages found matching courier*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching sendmail*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching sensible-mda
```

And then install courier-mta:

```
root@treebeard:/etc/logcheck/violations.ignore.d$ sudo aptitude install courier-mta
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  courier-authdaemon{a} courier-authlib{a} courier-authlib-userdb{a} courier-base{a} courier-mta 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,261 kB of archives. After unpacking 2,887 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] 
Preconfiguring packages ...              
Configuring courier-base
------------------------

Courier uses several configuration files in /etc/courier. Some of these files can be replaced by a subdirectory whose contents are concatenated and treated as a single, consolidated, configuration file.

The web-based administration provided by the courier-webadmin package relies on configuration directories instead of configuration files. If you agree, any directories needed for the web-based administration tool
will be created unless there is already a plain file in place.

Create directories for web-based administration? no


Configuring courier-mta
-----------------------

Please specify a valid email domain. Most header rewriting functions will append this domain to all email addresses which do not specify a domain, such as local accounts.

Default domain: fake.domain


Please specify a valid value for the "From" header for mail delivery notifications. These notifications cannot be sent without that setting.

"From" header for delivery notifications: noreply@fake.domain


Selecting previously unselected package courier-authlib.
(Reading database ... 249566 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking courier-authlib (from .../courier-authlib_0.63.0-6+b1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package courier-authdaemon.
Unpacking courier-authdaemon (from .../courier-authdaemon_0.63.0-6+b1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package courier-authlib-userdb.
Unpacking courier-authlib-userdb (from .../courier-authlib-userdb_0.63.0-6+b1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package courier-base.
Unpacking courier-base (from .../courier-base_0.68.2-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package courier-mta.
Unpacking courier-mta (from .../courier-mta_0.68.2-1_i386.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/addcr to /usr/bin/addcr.ucspi-tcp by courier-mta'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/addcr.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/addcr.ucspi-tcp.1.gz by courier-mta'
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up courier-authlib (0.63.0-6+b1) ...
Setting up courier-authdaemon (0.63.0-6+b1) ...
[ ok ] Starting Courier authentication services: authdaemond.
Setting up courier-authlib-userdb (0.63.0-6+b1) ...
Setting up courier-base (0.68.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/deliverquota.courier to provide /usr/bin/deliverquota (deliverquota) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man5/maildir.5.gz (maildir.5.gz) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/maildirmake.courier to provide /usr/bin/maildirmake (maildirmake) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man7/maildirquota.courier.7.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man7/maildirquota.7.gz (maildirquota.7.gz) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/makedat.courier to provide /usr/bin/makedat (makedat) in auto mode
Setting up courier-mta (0.68.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lockmail.courier to provide /usr/bin/lockmail (lockmail) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/preline.courier to provide /usr/bin/preline (preline) in auto mode
Starting Courier mail server: done.
Starting Courier mail filter: done.
Starting Courier SMTP server: done.
                                         
Current status: 0 broken [-2].
```

## The problem

courier-mta appeared to have installed without error, and yet courier-mta is not installed.  Instead, sendmail is installed:

```
root@treebeard:/etc/logcheck/violations.ignore.d$ dpkg -l 'courier*' 'sendmail*' 'exim*' sensible-mda
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-===================================================================================================
ii  courier-authdaemon                              0.63.0-6+b1                  i386                         Courier authentication daemon
ii  courier-authlib                                 0.63.0-6+b1                  i386                         Courier authentication library
ii  courier-authlib-userdb                          0.63.0-6+b1                  i386                         userdb support for the Courier authentication library
un  courier-authmysql                               <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  courier-authpostgresql                          <none>                                                    (no description available)
ii  courier-base                                    0.68.2-1                     i386                         Courier mail server - base system
un  courier-debug                                   <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  courier-doc                                     <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  courier-faxmail                                 <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  courier-filter-perl                             <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  courier-imap                                    <none>                                                    (no description available)
rc  courier-mta                                     0.68.2-1                     i386                         Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon
un  couriergrey                                     <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  exim4                                           <none>                                                    (no description available)
ii  sendmail                                        8.14.4-4                     all                          powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
ii  sendmail-base                                   8.14.4-4                     all                          powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
ii  sendmail-bin                                    8.14.4-4                     i386                         powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
ii  sendmail-cf                                     8.14.4-4                     all                          powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
un  sendmail-doc                                    <none>                                                    (no description available)
un  sendmail-tls                                    <none>                                                    (no description available)
ii  sensible-mda                                    8.14.4-4                     i386                         Mail Delivery Agent wrapper
```

sendmail-bin (and its requirements) have been installed.  Packages required by courier-mta have been installed, but courier-mta itself has not.

## History

This is a Debian Wheezy (stable) box.  It was running Debian Jessy (testing), but I downgraded it to Wheezy by means of this /etc/apt/preferences file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

and by changing /etc/apt/sources file to:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

and by a means of a long series of apt-get/dpkg commands which I do not recall.  I do recall there being much swearing.

## The question

**Why, when I try to install courier-mta, is sendmail-bin being installed instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I put some question, I usually test things on a clean virtual image to be sure my question did not depend on a misconfiguration.

Debian Stable (wheezy) VM:

```
apt-get install courier-mta sensible-mda
```

worked.

```
dpkg -l|grep -e mta -e  courier -e exim -e sendmail -e sensible
```

the output:

```
ii  courier-authdaemon                  0.63.0-6+b1                   i386         Courier authentication daemon
ii  courier-authlib                     0.63.0-6+b1                   i386         Courier authentication library
ii  courier-authlib-userdb              0.63.0-6+b1                   i386         userdb support for the Courier authentication library
ii  courier-base                        0.68.2-1                      i386         Courier mail server - base system
ii  courier-mta                         0.68.2-1                      i386         Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon
rc  exim4                               4.80-7                        all          metapackage to ease Exim MTA (v4) installation
rc  exim4-base                          4.80-7                        i386         support files for all Exim MTA (v4) packages
rc  exim4-config                        4.80-7                        all          configuration for the Exim MTA (v4)
rc  exim4-daemon-light                  4.80-7                        i386         lightweight Exim MTA (v4) daemon
ii  sensible-mda                        8.14.4-4                      i386         Mail Delivery Agent wrapper
ii  sensible-utils                      0.0.7                         all          Utilities for sensible alternative selection
```

no probs.

I did

```
time xz -dc debian-stable.img.xz >testsource.img
xz: debian-stable.img.xz: ok

real    0m35.918s
user    0m32.130s
sys     0m1.126s
```

and started `kvm` with this image. I didn't take that long.

Comment: A great idea, and you've confirmed that it's a problem with my particular installation of Debian.  Thank you.  I imagine there's damage from my downgrade, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You're welcome. It was not my idea. This is a common way to send bug reports.